# Recursive function to get all unique combinations of two or more

Tags: javascript, recursion, combinations

I need to write a function that gets all unique combinations of two or more elements from an array of elements. I've been working on this for a few days now. I initially wrote separate functions to get a few different sized combinations, which helped me see how they're similar and I hoped would get me closer to a working solution than it has so far. This is what I have so far....

```
function getAll (elements, comboSize, startingIndex) {
  let finalStartingIndex = /*startingIndex + */elements.length - comboSize;
  let finalIndex = finalStartingIndex + 1;
  let tmpStartingIndex = startingIndex;
  let qstrings = [];

  if (finalIndex >= elements.length) {
    finalIndex = finalStartingIndex;
  }

  if (finalStartingIndex < finalIndex) {
    while (tmpStartingIndex <= finalStartingIndex) {
      let nextIndex = tmpStartingIndex + 1;

      while (nextIndex <= finalIndex) {
        let tmpComboSize = comboSize - 1;
        let tmpQstring = '';
        let newQstring = '';

        if (tmpComboSize > 1) {
          tmpQstring = getAll(elements, tmpComboSize, nextIndex);
          console.log('tmpQstring :: ', tmpQstring);
        }

        if (tmpQstring != '') {
          newQstring = elements[tmpStartingIndex] + ', ' + tmpQstring[nextIndex];
          console.log('tmpQstring[nextIndex] :: ', tmpQstring[nextIndex]);
          console.log('newQstring :: ', newQstring);
        }
        let qstring = elements[tmpStartingIndex] + ', ' + elements[nextIndex];
        qstrings.push(qstring);
        nextIndex++;
      }

      /*nextIndex = tmpStartingIndex;

      let tmpComboSize = comboSize - 1;

      if (tmpComboSize > 1) {
        let tmpQstring = getAll(elements, tmpComboSize, nextIndex);

        let stringVal = elements[tmpStartingIndex] + ', ' + tmpQstring[nextIndex];
        qstrings.push(stringVal);
      }*/
      tmpStartingIndex++;
    }
  } else {
    qstrings[finalStartingIndex] = elements[startingIndex] + ', ' + elements[finalStartingIndex];
    console.log(qstrings);
  }

  return qstrings;
}

function getAllTwo (elements, comboSize, startingIndex) {
  let finalStartingIndex = startingIndex + elements.length - comboSize;
  let finalIndex = finalStartingIndex + 1;
  let tmpStartingIndex = startingIndex;
  let qstrings = [];

  while (tmpStartingIndex <= finalStartingIndex) {
    let finalNextIndex = tmpStartingIndex + 1;

    while (finalNextIndex <= finalIndex) {
      let qstring = elements[tmpStartingIndex] + ', ' + elements[finalNextIndex];
      qstrings.push(qstring);
      finalNextIndex++;
    }

    tmpStartingIndex++;
  }

  return qstrings;
}

function getAllThree (elements, comboSize, startingIndex) {
  let finalStartingIndex = startingIndex + elements.length - comboSize;
  let finalFirstNextIndex = finalStartingIndex + 1;
  let finalIndex = finalFirstNextIndex + 1;
  let tmpStartingIndex = startingIndex;
  let qstrings = [];

  while (tmpStartingIndex <= finalStartingIndex) {
    let firstNextIndex = tmpStartingIndex + 1;

    while (firstNextIndex <= finalFirstNextIndex) {
      let finalNextIndex = firstNextIndex + 1;

      while (finalNextIndex <= finalIndex) {
        let qstring = elements[tmpStartingIndex] + ', ' + elements[firstNextIndex] + ', ' + elements[finalNextIndex];
        qstrings.push(qstring);
        finalNextIndex++;
      }

      firstNextIndex++;
    }

    tmpStartingIndex++;
  }

  return qstrings;
}

function getAllFour (elements, comboSize, startingIndex) {
  let finalStartingIndex = startingIndex + elements.length - comboSize;
  let finalFirstNextIndex = finalStartingIndex + 1;
  let finalSecondNextIndex = finalFirstNextIndex + 1;
  let finalIndex = finalSecondNextIndex + 1;
  let tmpStartingIndex = startingIndex;
  let qstrings = [];

  while (tmpStartingIndex <= finalStartingIndex) {
    let firstNextIndex = tmpStartingIndex + 1;

    while (firstNextIndex <= finalFirstNextIndex) {
      let secondNextIndex = firstNextIndex + 1;

      while (secondNextIndex <= finalSecondNextIndex) {
        let finalNextIndex = secondNextIndex + 1;

        while (finalNextIndex <= finalIndex) {
          let qstring = elements[tmpStartingIndex] + ', ' + elements[firstNextIndex] + ', ' + elements[secondNextIndex] + ', ' + elements[finalNextIndex];
          qstrings.push(qstring);
          finalNextIndex++;
        }

        secondNextIndex++;
      }

      firstNextIndex++;
    }

    tmpStartingIndex++;
  }

  return qstrings;
}

function getAllFive (elements, comboSize, startingIndex) {
  let finalStartingIndex = startingIndex + elements.length - comboSize;
  let firstFinalIndex = finalStartingIndex + 1;
  let secondFinalIndex = firstFinalIndex + 1;
  let thirdFinalIndex = secondFinalIndex + 1;
  let finalIndex = thirdFinalIndex + 1;
  let tmpStartingIndex = startingIndex;
  let qstrings = [];

  while (tmpStartingIndex <= finalStartingIndex) {
    let firstIndex = tmpStartingIndex + 1;

    while (firstIndex <= firstFinalIndex) {
      let secondIndex = firstIndex + 1;

      while (secondIndex <= secondFinalIndex) {
        let thirdIndex = secondIndex + 1;

        while (thirdIndex <= thirdFinalIndex) {
          let finalNextIndex = thirdIndex + 1;

          while (finalNextIndex <= finalIndex) {
            let qstring = elements[tmpStartingIndex] + ', ' + elements[firstIndex] + ', ' + elements[secondIndex] + ', ' + elements[thirdIndex] + ', ' + elements[finalNextIndex];
            qstrings.push(qstring);
            console.log('qstrings being built: ', qstrings);
            finalNextIndex++;
          }

          thirdIndex++;
        }

        secondIndex++;
      }

      firstIndex++;
    }

    tmpStartingIndex++;
  }

  return qstrings;
}

let finalStrings = [];
let elements = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

for (let comboSize = 2; comboSize <= elements.length; comboSize++) {
  let finalString = [];
  let tstFinalString = [];

  switch (comboSize) {
    case 2:
      tstFinalString = getAll(elements, comboSize, 0);
      //console.log('tstFinalString, comboSize 2 :: ', tstFinalString);
      //finalString = getAllTwo(elements, comboSize, 0);
      break;

    case 3:
      tstFinalString = getAll(elements, comboSize, 0);
      console.log('tstFinalString, comboSize 3 :: ', tstFinalString);
      //finalString = getAllThree(elements, comboSize, 0);
      break;

    /*case 4:
      finalString = getAllFour(elements, comboSize, 0);
      break;

    case 5:
      finalString = getAllFive(elements, comboSize, 0);
      console.log(finalString);
      break;*/

    default:
      break;
  }

  finalStrings.push(finalString);
}
```

The first function is my attempt at proper recursion. Currently, it can get all two element combinations, but it cannot go beyond that. I feel like there's something simple that I'm missing, and I just cannot see it. I wrote the other functions to help me think through the logic and to make sure I was getting the data I am expecting. Those functions do work, but obviously it's not scalable. Any help you can offer pointing out what I'm missing will be appreciated.

Oh, this is currently written in Javascript, if that matters.

Comment: This program would be `O(2^n)`. Are you sure you understand the problem correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this would be more or less the canonical way for `k` sized combinations.

```js
// return n choose k combinations
function choose(arr, k, prefix=[], i=0){
  // if the remainder of the array will complete the
  // combination length exactly, combine it with
  // the current prefix and add to results
  if (prefix.length + arr.length - i == k){
    return [prefix.concat(arr.slice(i))];

  // if the prefix is long enough, add it to the results
  } else if (prefix.length == k){
    return [prefix];

  // otherwise, push combinations with and without
  // the current element
  } else {
    return choose(arr, k, prefix.concat(arr[i]), i + 1)
      .concat(choose(arr, k, prefix, i + 1));
  }
}

let arr = ["A","B","C","D","E"];
console.log('Input: ' + JSON.stringify(arr) + '\n');
let cs = choose(arr, 3);
console.log('\nOutput:');
for (let c of cs)
  console.log(JSON.stringify(c));
```

To get all, we could do something like:

```js
function powerset(arr, prefix=[], i=0){
  if (i == arr.length)
    return [prefix];

  return powerset(arr, prefix.concat(arr[i]), i + 1)
    .concat(powerset(arr, prefix, i + 1));
}

let arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
let ps = powerset(arr);
for (let s of ps)
  console.log(JSON.stringify(s));
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. This is not a way I would have thought to solve this problem. I appreciate the comments in the code.

Comment: @ClementSmith you're welcome! (I also added code for just the powerset.)

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way using generators. The advantage of this approach is that the combinations are generated lazily. Depending on your computation, sometimes you may be able to arrive at your desired result before generating all combinations. Since many combinatory problems involve *huge* sets of combinations, we can potentially save a lot of resources from skipping the generation of unneeded combinations. Additionally, this concept could be expanded to work on infinite streams, where it's possible that an infinite number of combinations could result.

```js
const append = (xs, x) =>
  xs .concat ([ x ])

const ncomb = function* (n, xs = [])
{ const gen = function* (n, acc)
  { if (n === 0)
      yield acc
    else
      for (const x of xs)
        yield* gen (n - 1, append (acc, x))
  }
  yield* gen (n, [])
}

const data =
  [ 1, 2, 3 ]

const print = (...xs) =>
  console .log (...xs .map (x => JSON .stringify (x)))

print
  ( Array .from (ncomb (0, data))
    // [[]]
    
  , Array .from (ncomb (1, data))
    // [[1],[2],[3]]
    
  , Array .from (ncomb (2, data))
    // [[1,1],[1,2],[1,3],[2,1],[2,2],[2,3],[3,1],[3,2],[3,3]]
    
  , Array .from (ncomb (3, data))
    // [[1,1,1],[1,1,2],[1,1,3],[1,2,1],[1,2,2],[1,2,3],[1,3,1],[1,3,2],[1,3,3],[2,1,1],[2,1,2],[2,1,3],[2,2,1],[2,2,2],[2,2,3],[2,3,1],[2,3,2],[2,3,3],[3,1,1],[3,1,2],[3,1,3],[3,2,1],[3,2,2],[3,2,3],[3,3,1],[3,3,2],[3,3,3]]
  )
```

Above the combinations increment the rightmost element, but this ordering can be changed. If you change the `append` operation to `prepend` you will generate combinations where the leftmost element increments instead –

```js
const prepend = (xs, x) =>
  [ x ] .concat (xs)

print
  ( Array .from (ncomb (3, data))
    // [[1,1,1],[2,1,1],[3,1,1],[1,2,1],[2,2,1],[3,2,1],[1,3,1],[2,3,1],[3,3,1],[1,1,2],[2,1,2],[3,1,2],[1,2,2],[2,2,2],[3,2,2],[1,3,2],[2,3,2],[3,3,2],[1,1,3],[2,1,3],[3,1,3],[1,2,3],[2,2,3],[3,2,3],[1,3,3],[2,3,3],[3,3,3]]
  )
```

To demonstrate the short-circuit behavior of the generator, consider a function `solve` which takes any amount of numbers and returns the first [Pythagorean triple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple). After the first right triangle is found, no additional combinations will be generated -

```
const isRightTriangle = (a, b, c) =>
  // pythagorean triple
  (a ** 2) + (b ** 2) === (c ** 2)

const solve = (...numbers) =>
{ for (const [ a, b, c ] of ncomb (3, numbers))
    if (isRightTriangle (a, b, c))
      return `solution: ${a}, ${b}, ${c}`
  return `no solution`
}

console .log (solve (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10))
// solution: 3, 4, 5

console .log (solve (8, 11, 6, 9, 5, 10, 12, 7))
// solution: 8, 6, 10

console .log (solve (19, 6, 8, 7, 21, 4, 3, 15))
// no solution
```

Expand the snippet below to verify the results in your own browser -

```js
const append = (xs, x) =>
  xs .concat ([ x ])

const ncomb = function* (n, xs = [])
{ const gen = function* (n, acc)
  { if (n === 0)
      yield acc
    else
      for (const x of xs)
        yield* gen (n - 1, append (acc, x))
  }
  yield* gen (n, [])
}

const isTriangle = (a, b, c) =>
  // pythagorean theorem
  (a ** 2) + (b ** 2) === (c ** 2)

const solve = (...numbers) =>
{ for (const [ a, b, c ] of ncomb (3, numbers))
    if (isTriangle (a, b, c))
      return `solution: ${a}, ${b}, ${c}`
  return `no solution`
}

console .log (solve (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10))
// solution: 3, 4, 5

console .log (solve (8, 11, 6, 9, 5, 10, 12, 7))
// solution: 8, 6, 10

console .log (solve (19, 6, 8, 7, 21, 4, 3, 15))
// no solution
```